# Issue with appending html for partial view via jQuery in ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, partial-views

I seem to be unable to find an answer to this issue, so here it is:

I created an ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 Entity Framework Code-First Migrations application.
In the Create view for one of the entities, I render a Partial View that I created:

```
        <div class="container" id="Things">
            <partial name="_CreateThingPartial" for="Things[0]" />
        </div>
```

This renders just fine.

I want to append another rendering of the same partial view in that container with the click of a button.  Here is my current jQuery:

```
var y = 0;

    $('#addThing').click(function () {
        y = y + 1;
        var newDiv = '<partial name="_CreateThingPartial" for="Things[' + y + ']" />';
        $('#Things').append(newDiv);
    });
```

But with this, clicking the button is doing nothing, and I can't figure out why.

If I simply add that html line in the view, like this:

```
        <div class="container" id="Things">
            <partial name="_CreateThingPartial" for="Things[0]" />
            <partial name="_CreateThingPartial" for="Things[1]" />
        </div>
```

That renders fine.

If I set the newDiv like this:

```
var newDiv = '<input type="button" value=' + y + ' />';
```

That works fine!

So it seems to only be an issue with the use of the partial view via jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `<partial>` is not a HTML tag. it's a server-side tag helper defined by .NET Core.

Consider your `Things` entities. It's stored in the database. Unless you render all the entities in your .cshtml file, you can't have them in client side without sending additional requests to your server.

`<partial>` tag helper is executed when rendering the resultant HTML markup **at the server**, while jQuery is executed **at the client** (e.g. browser). That's why you cannot simply put the `<partial>` inside your jQuery and get the data you want.

#### Possible solution

The following code snippets show you the **idea** on how to handle this problem. Copy-and-paste directly does not work. You have to understand the concept and do some google search in order to make it works.

You can define a **partial action** in your controller:

```cs
public ActionResult GetThingPartial (int id)
{
    /* get Thing[id] from database using EF Core */
    var videModel = Thing[id];
    return PartialView( "_CreateThingPartial", viewModel );
}
```

Fetch the partial result using jQuery's ajax call.

In your .cshtml file:

```js
var url = '@Url.Action("GetThingPartial", "YourControllerName")';

$.get(url, function(data) {
    /* append the data, which should be the partial HTML, to the corresponding <div> */
});
```

This article may also helpful to solve the problem you met: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/manas1/sending-partialview-using-jquery-ajax-request-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Thank you - this did help....I ended up doing it using ajax instead of .get, similar to what's in the article you linked.

Comment: Good to hear that! Note: `$.get()` method is a shorthand of `$.ajax()`. If you need to have some advanced configurations when calling the ajax call then go for `$.ajax()`. `$.get()` here just gives an idea on how to handle the frontend part (because the **partial action** is the main point of this solution.)

Answer (score 0):

partial is not a html tag but is related to how the .net razor template renders a partial view. So the actual HTML renderd on the page will not be partial but the content of the partial file _CreateThingPartial.

However when you modify the page with jQuery it is done in the frontend and the backend logic of your razor template will not be known. So when you try and add a tag called partial it will not be allowed because in the frontend that is not a valid tag.

To get a better understanding of how the .net razor template renders to the frontend i would sugest you open the view source or inspection page.

Comment: Oh, I see!  Thank you for that explanation!  So does that mean there really isn't a way to do this using the handy .net core html tag helpers, then?

Comment: The tag helpers are rendered in the backend and jquery is executed on the frontend so no. If you wish to do complex dom manipulation in the frontend i sugest rendering it there to begin with a frontend framework such as Vue or React. But that can also be overkill depending on the scope of the site.